# To what value does the following series converge to?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am asked to sum the series
$$1+\frac1{2}+\frac1{3}+\frac1{4}+\frac1{6}+\frac1{8}+\frac1{9}+\frac1{12}+\cdots$$
where the terms are the reciprocals of all positive integers whose only prime factors are two and threes.
What I tried so far is:

$$\frac1{2^03^0}+\frac1{2^13^0}+\frac1{2^03^1}+\frac1{2^23^0}+\frac1{2^13^1}+\frac1{2^33^0}+\frac1{2^03^2}+\frac1{2^23^1}+\cdot\cdot\cdot$$
The equence is in the form: $$\frac1{2^n3^m}$$
but what do I do know? I am stuck!

Comment: For fixed $n$, sum over $m$ (which you can, a geometric series). Then sum over $n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your series is$$\left(1+\frac12+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{2^3}+\cdots\right)\times\left(1+\frac13+\frac1{3^2}+\frac1{3^3}+\cdots\right).$$Therefore, its sum is$$2\times\frac32=3.$$

Comment: It was that easy? Thank you!